# Maintenance page for per-site metas is not localized

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, localization, maintenance

Each non-English Stack Overflow site has its own localized page for maintenance period. E.g. the following one on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour):

> [image]

There are still [some problems](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9392/176217) waiting for a fixes by the development team, but the current one I want to report about is related to meta sites. For some reason, per-site meta sites has an English page during maintenance (even the logo icon part and the site name):

> [image]

That might be by-design since a lot of mechanisms don't work during maintenance. Nevertheless, I've decided to report about it.